# getting expected identifier error in windows script host using vbscript

Tags: wsh

I'm writing windows script host code on login and logout session. When user logs into the system, a timestamp is being recorded and when user logs out again timestamp is being recorded. I have mentioned code below but getting an error as expected identifier and I'm finding it difficult to resolve it.

REM Login Script:

```
for /f "Tokens=2 Delims=[]" %%i in ('ping -n 1 "%computername%"') do set IP=%%i

echo %username% logged ON %computername%, IP=%IP% @ %time% %date% >> F:\$\%username%.txt
```

REM Logoff Script:

```
echo %username% logged OFF %computername% @ %time% %date% >> F:\$\%username%.txt
```

REM Startup Script:

```
for /f "Tokens=2 Delims=[]" %%i in ('ping -n 1 "%computername%"') do set IP=%%i
echo Started up, IP=%IP% @ %time% %date% >> F:\$\%computername%.txt
```

REM Shutdown Script:

```
echo Shutdown @ %time% %date% >> F:\$\%computername%.txt
```